# Will I see a difference in my photos if I aim my flash to the umbrella axis?

Tags: flash, lighting, umbrella

I've seen people over the internet aiming their flashes to the umbrella's axis but haven't seen yet a before and after photo. In my case, the flash aims a bit above the axis. What would be the benefit of aiming the flash to the umbrella's axis?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The benefit should be a bit better effectiveness of the umbrella and less spill outside. If your flash isn't significantly off I doubt that the change will be noticable.

Comment: Basically, it'd be best to just try it and see what happens. :-)

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but as Rismo would surely come up with that by himself I concluded he has some kind of fixed flash-umbrella mount that doesn't let him try that and wonders whether he should get a different one.

Comment: You're right che, the flash bracket I'm using to mount my flash and umbrella to my light stand won't let me aim the flash to the axis, it will aim it a bit higher.

Answer (score 7):

Asymmetric lighting of umbrella may also show up as asymmetric [catchlights](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11657/4390) in subjects' eyes.